# 360º image sequence for Android

Tags: android, image, performance, sequence, 360-degrees

I need to develop a 360º image sequence view for Android, similar to Apple's 360º demo. Something like what I made sometime ago:

http://www.fvalente.org/blog/2011/12/19/fvimagesequence-for-mac-os-xios/

The problem is that the images are about 1024x768 and they're way too slow to load on Android. The lag makes it look just awful. Both setImageDrawable and canvas do not work as expected(i.e. too slow). I cannot scale them down that much. Does anyone have any idea of a way to make it look smooth?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't tell what this looks like and the blog post only links to apple.com where they've changed whatever sequence you were thinking of. Any chance to add in some screenshots or video?

Comment: Why not reduce the size of the images?  That sounds pretty big for a phone (may be fine on tablets, though).

Comment: Kristy, it's supposed to run on a tablet, not on a phone.

Comment: Morrison, check this out: http://code4app.net/ios/360-Degrees-Image-Sequence/4fb090c56803fa2563000001